# How to type in HINDI (Krutidev) in TinyMCE Editor running at Ubuntu Server?

Tags: php, ubuntu, fonts, tinymce, font-face

I am using TinyMCE Editor for default editor at ubuntu server, I just want to copy and paste my HINDI statements from MS-Word (Krutidev) to Editor. When i do this i am getting output like this

```
bZ’kk us ` 1600 dh /kujkf’k dks 2 lky ds fy, fuos’k fd;k rFkk lky ds vUr esa mUgsa ` 1764 dk feJ/ku izkIr gqvk rks  C;kt nj Kkr djsaA
```

What is the way to type hindi in TinyMCE Editor ?

EDIT :

Already Installed fonts-indic package by using

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-indic
```

`language: 'hi_IN'`  is not a good idea for selecting fonts.

I want to use `Remington Gail/CBI Keyboard` for typing

Comment: What statements are inside the MS-Word document before you copy those contents? What happens if you copy the word content to another editor like notepad? Are the characters shown correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To change your TinyMCE language to Hindi, you'll need to include this property in your TinyMCE init.

`language: 'hi_IN'`

Comment: unfortunatly, this will only affect the tinymce ui - not the entered characters

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you will need to load the `Kruti Dev 0101` font inside the editor head to make your characters show.

You can do this by setting the tinymce editor init parameter `content_css` (https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css):

```
content_css: "../path/to/my/file.css";
```

and add a font face declaration inside that css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Kruti Dev 010";
    src: url("../path_to_ttf-file/kruti.ttf");
}
body{
  font-family:'Kruti Dev 010', Verdana;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the font your system for it to be detected. Download the font from the following link http://fonts.webtoolhub.com/font-n17979-kruti-dev-010.aspx Then move the font file to your /usr/share/fonts/truetype directory. Hope this helps.